# CommunityToolkit.MVVM ObservableValidator prevents ViewModel from Inheriting from BaseViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When attempting to change a ViewModel from an ObservableObject to ObservableValidator the compiler throws

```
Error CS0653 Cannot apply attribute class 'ObservableValidator' because it is abstract
```

Simplified original working class definition that inherits from ViewModelBase so that navigation works.

```cs
[ObservableObject]
internal sealed partial class AddSimCardViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly NavigationService _addSimCardViewNavigationService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _phoneNumber;
    
    public AddSimCardViewModel(NavigationService addSimCardViewNavigationService)
    {
        _addSimCardViewNavigationService = addSimCardViewNavigationService;        
    }
}
```

Simplified replacement class definition that throws error

```cs
[ObservableValidator]
internal sealed partial class AddSimCardViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly NavigationService _addSimCardViewNavigationService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _phoneNumber;
    
    public AddSimCardViewModel(NavigationService addSimCardViewNavigationService)
    {
        _addSimCardViewNavigationService = addSimCardViewNavigationService;        
    }
}
```

```cs
internal sealed partial class AddSimCardViewModel : ViewModelBase, ObservableObject
```

and

```cs
internal sealed partial class AddSimCardViewModel : ViewModelBase, ObservableValidator
```

won't work as both Observable classes are base classes.

If ObservableValidator won't work as an attribute how could I change my NavigationService to work with differnet ViewModels?

```cs
internal class ViewModelBase 
{
    public virtual void Dispose() { }
}

internal sealed class NavigationService
{
    private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;
    private readonly Func<ViewModelBase> _createViewModel;

    public NavigationService(NavigationStore navigationStore,
                           Func<ViewModelBase> createViewModel)
    {
        _navigationStore = navigationStore;
        _createViewModel = createViewModel;
    }
    internal void Navigate()
    {
        _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = _createViewModel();
    }
}
```

Edited to add NavigationStore that calls Dispose on ViewModel

I have been using https://github.com/SingletonSean/reservoom as the basis for this project.

```cs
internal sealed class NavigationStore
{
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
    internal ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get => _currentViewModel;
        set
        {
            _currentViewModel?.Dispose();
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnCurrentViewModelChanged();
        } 
    }

    public event Action CurrentViewModelChanged;

    private void OnCurrentViewModelChanged()
    {
        CurrentViewModelChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have in viewmodelbase is dispose and it has no implementation.

That should be an interface ( but do you really need it at all ?).

You can implement as many interfaces as you like in a class, but inherit from only one class.

Then your viewmodels can inherit observableobject or observablevalidator and implement whatever interfaces you like.

In order to avoid any confusion, I prefer not to use attributes for the classes and instead use regular c#:

```
    public partial class NewTransactionViewModel : ObservableValidator, IInitiatedViewModel
```

My thinking:

One should avoid having any need to explicitly dispose anything out a viewmodel. Only reference private members with any event handling. Use weak events or weak event event messenger across objects. Have small methods with use to instantiate anything where disposing is critical.  There are very few things I find I need to explicitly dispose.

Use an interface for anything you want all viewmodels to do.

I have

```
interface IInitiatedViewModel
{
    Task Initiate();
}
```

Any viewmodel set up is then done in the initiate task.

I can then do something like:

```
  await Task.Run(() =>((IInitiatedViewModel)CurrentViewModel).Initiate());
```

On any viewmodel I just instantiated and it gets it's data etc.

If there's no setup then don't apply that interface.

Comment: I have edited my question to add the NavigationStore which calls the ViewModel Dispose and the GitHub project which is used as the basis for the project in question

Comment: You can just define an idispose interface if you feel you need a dispose method @JCL